# How to increase stack limit from 1GB

Tags: go

I purposely want to increase the stacksize beyond 1GB for a large problem. I do not have an infinite recursive loop.

Currently, I get:

```
runtime: goroutine stack exceeds 1000000000-byte limit
fatal error: stack overflow
```

How do I increase it to 2GB?

Comment: Instead of increasing the stack size can you allocate some of this memory ahead of time and store it on the heap?

Comment: @user2896976 I could, if I have to, but I have a machine with 64GB I'm running this on so if I don't have to, I would prefer not to.

Comment: Try [`debug.SetMaxStack`](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/debug#SetMaxStack) (found via [a RosettaCode post](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Find_limit_of_recursion#Go)).

Comment: 1GB is a very large stack, regardless of the physical memory available. I'd be very concerned about any code that can consume that much stack memory outside of an infinite recursion. Why do you say you would "prefer not to" allocate to the heap? Can you provide any more details about the implementation?